# ¿leer numeros juntos en un txt?

Tags: python, lista

Tengo la siguiente lista de numeros los cuales estan en un .txt:
6 28 12 3 10 22 26 7 10
necesito que el programa sepa que lo que lee es un 28, 12 o 22 por ejemplo. 
para luego poder meterlos en una lista.

Answer (score 3):

Con esto leemos el archivo y lo guardamos en una variable. El código `with` se asegura de abrir y cerrar el archivo al ejecutarse el bloque.

```
with open("mifichero.txt", "r") as leyendo:
  datos = leyendo.read()
```

Ahora ya simplemente mételos en una lista. El comando `split` dividirá los números cada vez que se encuentre un espacio.

```
mi_lista = datos.split(" ")
```

Pero todo eso es texto, si lo necesitas como íntegros, guárdalos así:

```
mi_lista = [int(x) for x in datos.split(" ") if not " " in x ]
```

Para comprobarlo:

```
print(mi_lista)
```

Comment: mucha gracias, lo probare

Comment: Espero que te sirva. Si la respuesta es válida, acuérdate de aceptarla usando el tick verde del menú de la izquierda (donde están las flechitas). Si tienes alguna duda al respecto, por favor compartela y te ayudaremos.